# What do Ctrl+number keys do in a terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

I am attempting to fill my keyboard with more bindings for tmux and vim, and I thought about using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc.

In tmux <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> caused it to create a vertical split, which was interesting, then I tried it outside of tmux inside of cat and got this:

```
% cat
^@^[^\[1]    5730 quit (core dumped)  cat
```

Here I typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (produced no output), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (^@), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (^[), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> after which point it promptly died like this.

Now I will say that I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> bound to vertical split in tmux, so that makes sense, but at this point I'm wondering why these bindings are like this. I fear that it means I can never distinguish e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> from the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Comment: These results are going to depend highly on what terminal program you are using, and maybe even on your shell. Or, your window manager might even capture them first... In other words, there's not a lot that can be usefully said without knowing a lot more about your exact setup...

Comment: Can you tell us which distro and version of Linux/Unix you're using?

Comment: I take it, then, that these key combinations are in an unregulated "no man's land". I am on a fork of PuTTY so I imagine I can with a high degree of certainty track down what it is precisely doing by looking in the source code. Same goes for the other terminal I use which is iTerm2. I will probably be able to create my own binds (to my own custom escape codes) through configuration and source code changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a real definite answer. It's all based on the operating system you're using. For example, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on one computer, and its key bindings are different than what I have another system with an older version that I keep as a server.